# What is "-t" in a bash script?

Tags: bash, shell

After quite a bit of Google searching I can't seem to find the answer. What does the -t do in the context of this code?

```
if [ ! -t 1 ]
then
    SCRIPTLOG=$LOG_DIR/$SCRIPT.log
    exec >>$SCRIPTLOG 2>&1
    chmod 644 $SCRIPTLOG
fi
```

Comment: This didn't answer my question directly at all, but it did give me information I needed to search and provide my own answer.

Comment: Do a `help test` in the bash console

Comment: See also [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389495/what-does-t-1-check)

Comment: `[` is shorthand for the command `test`. So you can do `man test` to see the `test` command's manual where all of these flags are listed.